# Почему применение CSS-фильтра к родительскому элементу нарушает позиционирование дочернего элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, css-animation

Итак, у меня есть «анимация» титульного экрана, в которой заголовок **Title** сосредоточен  на полноэкранной странице, и при прокрутке вниз он становится меньше и остается в верхней части страницы. Вот рабочий пример с ожидаемым поведением, из которого я удалил весь ненужный код, чтобы сделать его минимальным:

```js
$(window).scroll( () => {
    "use strict";
    let windowH = $(window).height();
    let windowS = $(window).scrollTop();
    let header  = $("#header").height(); 
    
    if (windowS < windowH-header) {
        $("#title").css("transform", "scale("+(2-(windowS/($(document).outerHeight()-windowH))*2.7)+")");
        $("#header").css("transform", "translateY(0)");
        $("#inside, #content").css({
            "position": "static",
            "margin-top": 0
        });
    } else {
        $("#inside").css({
            "position": "fixed",
            "margin-top": -windowH+header
        });
        $("#content").css("margin-top", windowH);
    }
  
    $("#header").css("position", windowS > (windowH-header)/2 ? "fixed" :"static");
});
```

```css
.fixed {
    position: fixed!important;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper:before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
.wrapper:after {
    clear: both;
}
#inside {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#header {
    height: 90px;
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
#title {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(2);
}
#content {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>  
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="inside">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Далее идет тот же самый фрагмент, но с одним дополнением: я применил фильтр, который, на мой взгляд, носит чисто косметический характер: `filter: Brightness(1.3);`.

Как вы можете видеть ниже, когда вы прокручиваете половину «анимации», заголовок просто исчезает. Когда вы проверяете элемент, он по-прежнему сохраняет все свои свойства, но каким-то образом его нет. То же самое происходит в Firefox и Chrome, и я понятия не имею, почему.
Я был бы очень признателен, если бы кто-нибудь опубликовал рабочий фрагмент с примененным фильтром и объяснил, почему он не работал раньше.

```js
$(window).scroll( () => {
    "use strict";
    let windowH = $(window).height();
    let windowS = $(window).scrollTop();
    let header  = $("#header").height(); 
    
    if (windowS < windowH-header) {
        $("#title").css("transform", "scale("+(2-(windowS/($(document).outerHeight()-windowH))*2.7)+")");
        $("#header").css("transform", "translateY(0)");
        $("#inside, #content").css({
            "position": "static",
            "margin-top": 0
        });
    } else {
        $("#inside").css({
            "position": "fixed",
            "margin-top": -windowH+header
        });
        $("#content").css("margin-top", windowH);
    }
  
    $("#header").css("position", windowS > (windowH-header)/2 ? "fixed" :"static");
});
```

```css
.fixed {
    position: fixed!important;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper:before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
.wrapper:after {
    clear: both;
}
#inside {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    filter: brightness(1.3);        /*<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*/
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#header {
    height: 90px;
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
#title {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(2);
}
#content {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>  
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="inside">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Почему применение CSS-фильтра к родительскому элементу нарушает позиционирование дочернего элемента?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52937708/7394871) от участника  [@leonheess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7910454/leonheess).</sub>

Comment: Думаю дело в этом. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937708/why-does-applying-a-css-filter-on-the-parent-break-the-child-positioning

Comment: @HTOHOT, Вы не поняли - этот вопрос не про владение поисковиками, а "на подумать", разобраться и дать внятный ответ _на русском языке_. В общем, зря Вы так, Вадим.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937708/why-does-applying-a-css-filter-on-the-parent-break-the-child-positioning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$(window).scroll( () => {
    "use strict";
    let windowH = $(window).height();
    let windowS = $(window).scrollTop();
    let header  = $("#header").height(); 
    
    if (windowS < windowH-header) {
        $("#title").css("transform", "scale("+(2-(windowS/($(document).outerHeight()-windowH))*2.7)+")");
        $("#header").css("transform", "translateY(0)");
        $("#inside, #content").css({
            "position": "static",
            "margin-top": 0
        });
    } else {
        $("#inside").css({
            "position": "fixed",
            "margin-top": -windowH+header
        });
        $("#content").css("margin-top", windowH);
    }
  
    $("#header").css("position", windowS > (windowH-header)/2 ? "fixed" :"static");
});
```

```css
.fixed {
    position: fixed!important;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper:before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
.wrapper:after {
    clear: both;
}
#inside {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    filter: brightness(1.3);        /*<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*/
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#header {
    height: 90px;
    top: 250px;   /* !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    по всплывашке на потолке в консоли, можно было
    догадаться, что оно уехало куда то вверх. FF 91.6
    а вот почему уехало... это уже хороший вопрос)))
    fixed fixed'у родитель, контейнер и запасной потолок :3
    похоже top: 0 то на край окна, то на край родителя
    тригерится, начхав на то, что тот fixed в обоих случаях.
    учитывая что он должен цепляться за окно только
    если родитель static... выходит вопрос не в том почему
    исчезал с фильтром, вопрос в том, почему не исчезал
    без него :3 */
    position: sticky;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
#title {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(2);
}
#content {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>  
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="inside">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо за хороший ответ! Мне понравилось ваше стремление: разобраться, понять причину. Это самое главное. Посмотрел ваши другие ответы. Вполне нормально. Жаль что люди стали такие инертные, сил наверное у них уж нет, не то чтоб разобраться, комментарий написать а даже передвинуть мышку для плюсика. Ведь автору всегда приятно получить положительный кэшбек за потраченные усилия. Ответ приму позже, если не появятся более сильные ответы. Хотя это врядли произойдет

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, всегда пожалуйста :3 думал ща минусов прилетит за островатую манеру изложения, да и за то что инфу из ссылки на инглиш не учел(пока писал одним глазом уже сны смотрел) ан не, даже в плюсе внезапно) а на счет инертности... к css и прочим стоковым технологиям у народа нынче в целом отношение, как к IE5 примерно. ну оно и понятно: `чо с ними возиться когда реактов с вуями наплодилось вагон и маленькая тележка`

Comment: согласен, но есть нюанс никакой реакт и другие крутые фреймворки не помогут, если например есть серьезная ошибка в коде. На Enso ежедневно по нескольку вопросов типа, почему мое реакт приложение не работает? Почти 100% это коренная ошибка в коде модуле, например SVG, а в реакте всё нормально.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, для того мы и есть :3 интересующиеся гхм... низкоуровневым кодом...) то самое чувство когда назвал css низкоуровневым и это уже коррелирует с реальностью...))))

Answer (score 2):

На вопрос почему это так работает, я к сожалению ответить не смогу (возможно это баг, или фича для фикса неких багов). Я попытался разобраться и видимо блок с `filter` выступает как некий `relative` блок в том числе и для дочерних блоков с `position:fixed`. И это при том, что сам блок с `filter` имеет `position:static`.

```js
const wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');
const someBlock = document.querySelector('.some-block');
const toggleF = document.querySelector('button');
const radioElems = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="position"]');
radioElems.forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            someBlock.style.position = e.target.value;
            if (e.target.value === 'static') {
                someBlock.style.transform = 'translate(0,0)'
            } else {
                someBlock.style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%)'
            }
        }

    })
})
toggleF.addEventListener('click', () => {
    wrap.classList.toggle('filter')
})
```

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.filter {
    filter: brightness(1.3);
}

.wrap {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: brown;
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
}

.some-block {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 2px black solid;
}

.long-block {

    height: 200vh;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
        <div class="some-block">Block</div>
    </div>
    <div class="long-block">
        <button>Toggle Filter</button>
        <div>
            <p>Свойство position для "some-block"</p>
            <div>
                <label>absolute <input checked type="radio" value="absolute" name="position" id="absolute"></label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>static <input type="radio" value="static" name="position" id="static"></label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>fixed <input type="radio" value="fixed" name="position" id="fixed"></label>
            </div>


        </div>

    </div>
```

Моя попытка исправить ЭТОТ КОД, но НЕ ТАКОЕ ПОВЕДЕНИЕ `filter`

```js
$(window).scroll( () => {
    "use strict";
    let windowH = $(window).height();
    let windowS = $(window).scrollTop();
    let header  = $("#header").height(); 
    
    if (windowS < windowH-header) {
        $("#title").css("transform", "scale("+(2-(windowS/($(document).outerHeight()-windowH))*2.7)+")");
        $("#header").css("transform", "translateY(0)");
        $("#inside, #content").css({
            "position": "static",
            "margin-top": 0
        });
    } else {
        $("#inside").css({
            "position": "fixed",
            "margin-top": -windowH+header
        });
        $("#content").css("margin-top", windowH);
    }
    //// Здесь просто удалил position fixed для header
});
```

```css
.fixed {
    position: fixed!important;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper:before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
.wrapper:after {
    clear: both;
}
#inside {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    filter: brightness(1.3);        /*<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*/
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#header {
    height: 90px;
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
#title {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(2);
}
#content {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>  
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="inside">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

P.S. Немного погуглив наткнулся на ещё несколько свойств которые работают также. К примеру `transform:translate(0,0)` точно также изменит поведение дочернего absolute или fixed элемента.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, за попытку разобраться **(+)**  Это точно **не баг**, смотрите переведенный ответ, ссылки на спецификацию и я специально для вас перевел наиболее важные комментарии

Answer (score 1):

Если обратиться к [**спецификации**](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#FilterProperty), то можно прочитать:

> Значение свойства фильтра, отличное от `none`, приводит к созданию
> **содержащего блока для потомков с абсолютным и фиксированным расположением**, если только элемент, к которому оно применяется, не
> является корневым элементом документа в текущем контексте просмотра.
> Список функций применяется в указанном порядке.

Это означает, что ваш элемент `position:fixed` будет позиционироваться относительно фильтруемого контейнера, а не относительно области просмотра. Другими словами, он все еще `fixed`, но внутри нового содержащего блока (фильтрованного контейнера).
Вот упрощенная версия, иллюстрирующая проблему:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200vh;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.container>div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>I am fixed on scroll</div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="filter:grayscale(1);">
  <div>I move with the scroll</div>
</div>
```

Чтобы решить эту проблему, попробуйте переместить фильтр в фиксированный элемент, а не в его контейнер:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200vh;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.container>div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>I am fixed on scroll</div>
</div>
```

Вот неполный<sup>1</sup> список свойств, который приводит к созданию содержащего блока для абсолютных и фиксированных потомков:

- `filter`
- `transform` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#containing-block-for-all-descendants)</sup>
- `backdrop-filter` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects-2/#BackdropFilterProperty)</sup>
- `perspective` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#propdef-perspective)</sup>
- `contain` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain/)</sup>
- `container` <sup>[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74606435/8620333)</sup>
- `transform-style` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#transform-style-property)</sup>
- `content-visibility` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain/#containment-layout)</sup>
- `will-change` при использовании с одним из вышеуказанных значений

> Если какое-либо не начальное значение свойства приведет к тому, что элемент сгенерирует содержащий блок для абсолютно позиционированных элементов, указание этого свойства в `will-change` должно привести к тому, что элемент сгенерирует содержащий блок для абсолютно позиционированных элементов. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-will-change/#will-change)</sup>

<sup>1</sup>: Я постараюсь поддерживать этот список в актуальном состоянии..

***PS***

*Перевод наиболее значимых комментариев:*

**@MiXT4PE** это определено в спецификации, так что так и должно быть. Вы, вероятно, можете спросить, почему они определяют это именно так ... Я почти уверен, что за этим выбором стоит причина (вероятно, сложная). –
**@Temani Afif**

**@ygoe** во-первых, это не **bug**, это задумано, как и многие функции, которые нам не нравятся, но с которыми мы должны работать (очистить плавающее пространство, схлопывать поля и т. д.), поэтому вам следует адаптировать свой код, чтобы преодолеть это. Универсального решения не существует, но в зависимости от вашего случая наверняка найдется решение. Вы можете задать вопрос, добавив свой конкретный код, чтобы посмотреть, сможем ли мы изменить вашу логику, чтобы удовлетворить ваши требования и решить проблему. –
**@Temani Afif**

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937920/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>